# Will google accounts automatically update my friends addressbooks

Tags: contacts, sync

I was with Verizon Wireless when I had my HTC Eris (now due to issue with VZW and upgrading my phone I cancelled with VZW). I moved over to sprint and to a phone OS that shall not be named, but now I am on the verge of getting the Samsung Galaxy S4. During my switch, I did NOT keep my phone number and took a new number with Sprint. The problem is that my friends may still have my old number in their Google contacts and I am concerned that switching on the Galaxy S4 would cause Google to update my number to anyone who has my number in their Google contacts.

So my question is, if I link my Google account on to my new carrier/device, will Google update anyone who has my number in their Google contacts automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Their contact list (that is synced with the Google account) is based on the GMail contact list. It is a local copy; so any changes must be made from their side.

However, if they synced/merged that GMail contact to your Google Plus account, and you updated your contact information in Google Plus, it's still possible for them to know your new number.

Comment: I have that person blocked on Google+ so it won't be possible for her to get the number, but that is good to know. Thank you.